# How to get Excel Worksheet from sheets when a sheetname has spaces programatically

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I try to

```
var tempSheet = wrksheets[sheetName] as Worksheet;
```

where `wrksheets` is of type sheets 
sheetName is "sheet name with spaces"

If sheetName has no space, it works fine, but if it has space, I get an exception saying invalid index. I only know the name of work sheet, do not know its index. The only thing I can think of is to loop through sheets and compare name of each sheet with sheetName. Not efficient but is there a better way? thanks

Edit 
say sheet name is 'sheet name with spaces'
When I refer a cell in the sheet say A1, it will be 'sheet name with spaces'!A1 
when I use "'sheet name with spaces'" in wrksheets[sheetName], I get an invalid index exception 
I found the issue is I should use "sheet name with spaces" as sheetName instead of the original sheetname with single quotes.
So I write a function to remove invalid/escape chars in sheet name before getting sheet from wrksheets, then it works fine.

```
    private string RemoveEscapeCharsFromSheetName(string sheetName)
    {
        //TODO: should remove all chars that are not allowed in Excel Sheet Name
        sheetName = sheetName.Trim(new char[] { ' ', '\'' });
        return sheetName;
    }


        sheet = RemoveEscapeCharsFromSheetName(sheet);
        var tempSheet = wrksheets[sheet] as Worksheet;
```

Comment: Can you provide a real example as I've never had a problem with the scenario you are explaining, unless I am misunderstanding your scenario

Comment: Leaving the main problem aside, I don't see anything wrong with looping through your worksheets. Even if you had hundreds (I highly doubt it is in the dozens), the impact would be negligible.

Comment: do you have more code than just that one line..? this helps no one regards to providing you sufficient advice and or help

Answer (score 3):

Surround the worksheet name with quotes.

```
var tempSheet = wrksheets["\"" + sheetName + "\""] as Worksheet;
```